# Remote Access to VirtualBox: Can't Connect via Remote Desktop

Tags: tomcat, hudson, admin, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I have a host (Windows 7) and a VirtualBox on it (guest OS is Ubuntu), that uses the NAT adapter.
Also my host is in the local network (DHCP).

I have already set the ssh connection to the VB and also I have an Internet access from the guest OS.

Now I want to establish a remote connection to the Hudson which is running on Tomcat 6 which, in turn, is running on Ubuntu.
I have tried this:

1. `VB -> Settings -> Display -> Remote Display ->` checked enable server on 3389 port.
2. On my collegue's computer (Windows 7) opened `Start -> Program -> Accessories -> Remote Desktop Connection`.
   So that I use the NAT adapter my host and guest have the same ip.
   I have tried to connect to `myIpAddress:3389`, but it can't do this (not with the global id, nor with the local) [However It managed to connect to the host with the local ip].

Well, the other variant was to use the Bridge adapter.
But When I try to start the VM there is an error:

```
Unknown configuration node 
"//ssh" found in the configuration of IntNet instance #0 (VER_CGGM_CONFIG_UNKNOWN_NODE)
```

Did anybody face this problem?

Comment: I usually keep net0 as the standard network connection, and net1 as a bridge one. Then, `ifconfig` on Ubuntu (guest) gives me 2 addresses. I can use the second one from the host to access an httpd or sshd service.

Comment: why do you try to use Remote Desktop Connection ? If you try to access to your virtual machine thru SSH does it work?

Comment: Yes, I've managed to establish an ssh connection. Of course, I can ask my collegues to install Xming and use it via Putty, but it seems too overhead. The idea is to use the equipment they have... =)

Comment: Can anybody please explain why I get the "Unknown configuration node '//ssh' found in the configuration of IntNet instance " error (see question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the the remote display port is conflicting with your host Win7 remote desktop service or the windows firewall. I would suggest double checking the firewall settings and switching the remote display port in VirtualBox to something like 3390 (or some other unused port). I would consider it a "best practice" to change the Remote Display port to something other than 3389 with a Windows host.

As for the error with the bridged adapter, It would appear that you still have a port forward from the NAT configuration sticking around that is having trouble going away. Switch the adapter configuration back to NAT and clear out any settings that are present - trying adding a new rule, then saving and then removing it if none are showed to ensure the XML config file is updated.

Answer (score 0):

when running in Headless mode in windows firewall ports 5000-5010 are opened automatically try setting your port to one of these than try yourIPaddress:Portyouchoosen

Answer (score 0):

For linux:

`# ssh -X user@yourserver`

`# VirtualBox`

It will open an VirtualBox GUI from remmote server.
Just as fast as remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ssh user@ip -p portnumber
```